# Security Program feature in Lattice Diamond

Tags: lattice-diamond

I would like to use the security features in Lattice FPGA (Machxo3) and is currently stuck with Security Program Password feature. 
There are two options:

1. security program password key
2. security program password key with lock

Conversation with Lattice Technical Support brings me nowhere. Appreciate it if anyone who have used these feature can help to explain the differences between these two.

Here is the FAQ provided at their website: http://www.latticesemi.com/en/Support/AnswerDatabase/5/6/2/5628

My doubt was that since the key is stored in the feature row, assuming I only use Security Program Password Key, which allow me to erase the feature row, I can then erase the key which render the device unprotected again. After a couple of emails with the technical support guy, now he is telling me that option 1 does not secure the UFM but option 2 does; which totally diverge from what the FAQ says.

Appreciate it if someone can shed some light.